# Keen IO Dashboards drag & drop

Tags: keen-io

I'm looking at Keen IO Dashboards, but don't see drag & drop functionality in examples.  Is that possible and I'm just missing it, or is it planned?  Thanks.

Comment: We are not vendor support

Answer (score 5):

Keen released a new point-and-click dashboard creator that can be accessed when you're logged into your account. A few clicks can build metrics into dashboards you can share with your teammates. https://keen.io/blog/146028881101/announcing-keen-dashboards

Fully customizable external or customer-facing dashboards can be created using [keen-dataviz.js](https://github.com/keen/keen-dataviz.js) if you're into templates some [bootstrap dashboard templates](http://keen.github.io/dashboards/) can be downloaded from github too.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and Drop isn't currently supported but the team is very open to feature requests. I'd suggest filing in issue on the Github repository – [keen/dashboards](https://github.com/keen/dashboards).

If you want to discuss it further, Keen has a [developer group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/keen-io-devs).